# asp.net link button doesn't fire by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, onclick

I have a template which's link is http://livedemo00.template-help.com/wt_40086/index-6.html that I am trying to use this form. Just I need is e-mail validation, I added `notRequired` all other classes except email, and chenged link to asp:link button.
The form.js http://livedemo00.template-help.com/wt_40086/js/forms.js is sumbitted for php mailer, I don't use it I have onclick event and I want it to fire but it does not work.

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btn_calculate" CssClass="button" data-type="submit" OnClick="btn_calculate_Click" Text="Calculate"></asp:LinkButton>
```

This is my bu tton which is not firing. Js normally looks like working fine, if I do not fill email it shows me error. alltough I fill everything I cannot fire my onclick event....
--edit---
**I want that If email is correct, onclick will fire...**

But it does not :(

--edit 2----

```
//forms
;(function($){
    $.fn.forms=function(o){
        return this.each(function(){
            var th=$(this)
                ,_=th.data('forms')||{
                    errorCl:'error',
                    emptyCl:'empty',
                    invalidCl:'invalid',
                    notRequiredCl:'notRequired',
                    successCl:'success',
                    successShow:'4000',
                    mailHandlerURL:'bat/MailHandler.php',
                    ownerEmail:'support@guardlex.com',
                    stripHTML:true,
                    smtpMailServer:'localhost',
                    targets:'input,textarea',
                    controls:'a[data-type=reset],a[data-type=submit]',
                    validate:true,
                    rx:{
                        ".name":{rx:/^[a-zA-Z'][a-zA-Z-' ]+[a-zA-Z']?$/,target:'input'},
                        ".state":{rx:/^[a-zA-Z'][a-zA-Z-' ]+[a-zA-Z']?$/,target:'input'},
                        ".email":{rx:/^(("[\w-\s]+")|([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)|("[\w-\s]+")([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*))(@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$)|(@\[?((25[0-5]\.|2[0-4][0-9]\.|1[0-9]{2}\.|[0-9]{1,2}\.))((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\.){2}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\]?$)/i,target:'input'},
                        ".phone":{rx:/^\+?(\d[\d\-\+\(\) ]{5,}\d$)/,target:'input'},
                        ".fax":{rx:/^\+?(\d[\d\-\+\(\) ]{5,}\d$)/,target:'input'},
                        ".message":{rx:/.{20}/,target:'textarea'}
                    },
                    preFu:function(){
                        _.labels.each(function(){
                            var label=$(this),
                                inp=$(_.targets,this),
                                defVal=inp.val(),
                                trueVal=(function(){
                                            var tmp=inp.is('input')?(tmp=label.html().match(/value=['"](.+?)['"].+/),!!tmp&&!!tmp[1]&&tmp[1]):inp.html()
                                            return defVal==''?defVal:tmp
                                        })()
                            trueVal!=defVal
                                &&inp.val(defVal=trueVal||defVal)
                            label.data({defVal:defVal})                             
                            inp
                                .bind('focus',function(){
                                    inp.val()==defVal
                                        &&(inp.val(''),_.hideEmptyFu(label),label.removeClass(_.invalidCl))
                                })
                                .bind('blur',function(){
                                    _.validateFu(label)
                                    if(_.isEmpty(label))
                                        inp.val(defVal)
                                        ,_.hideErrorFu(label.removeClass(_.invalidCl))                                          
                                })
                                .bind('keyup',function(){
                                    label.hasClass(_.invalidCl)
                                        &&_.validateFu(label)
                                })
                            label.find('.'+_.errorCl+',.'+_.emptyCl).css({display:'block'}).hide()
                        })
                        _.success=$('.'+_.successCl,_.form).hide()
                    },
                    isRequired:function(el){                            
                        return !el.hasClass(_.notRequiredCl)
                    },
                    isValid:function(el){                           
                        var ret=true
                        $.each(_.rx,function(k,d){
                            if(el.is(k))
                                ret=d.rx.test(el.find(d.target).val())                                      
                        })
                        return ret                          
                    },
                    isEmpty:function(el){
                        var tmp
                        return (tmp=el.find(_.targets).val())==''||tmp==el.data('defVal')
                    },
                    validateFu:function(el){                            
                        el.each(function(){
                            var th=$(this)
                                ,req=_.isRequired(th)
                                ,empty=_.isEmpty(th)
                                ,valid=_.isValid(th)                                

                            if(empty&&req)
                                _.showEmptyFu(th.addClass(_.invalidCl))
                            else
                                _.hideEmptyFu(th.removeClass(_.invalidCl))

                            if(!empty)
                                if(valid)
                                    _.hideErrorFu(th.removeClass(_.invalidCl))
                                else
                                    _.showErrorFu(th.addClass(_.invalidCl))                             
                        })
                    },
                    getValFromLabel:function(label){
                        var val=$('input,textarea',label).val()
                            ,defVal=label.data('defVal')                                
                        return label.length?val==defVal?'nope':val:'nope'
                    }
                    ,submitFu:function(){
                        _.validateFu(_.labels)                          
                        if(!_.form.has('.'+_.invalidCl).length)
                            $.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                url:_.mailHandlerURL,
                                data:{
                                    name:_.getValFromLabel($('.name',_.form)),
                                    email:_.getValFromLabel($('.email',_.form)),
                                    phone:_.getValFromLabel($('.phone',_.form)),
                                    fax:_.getValFromLabel($('.fax',_.form)),
                                    state:_.getValFromLabel($('.state',_.form)),
                                    message:_.getValFromLabel($('.message',_.form)),
                                    owner_email:_.ownerEmail,
                                    stripHTML:_.stripHTML
                                },
                                success: function(){
                                    _.showFu()
                                }
                            })          
                    },
                    showFu:function(){
                        _.success.slideDown(function(){
                            setTimeout(function(){
                                _.success.slideUp()
                                _.form.trigger('reset')
                            },_.successShow)
                        })
                    },
                    controlsFu:function(){
                        $(_.controls,_.form).each(function(){
                            var th=$(this)
                            th
                                .bind('click',function(){
                                    _.form.trigger(th.data('type'))
                                    return false
                                })
                        })
                    },
                    showErrorFu:function(label){
                        label.find('.'+_.errorCl).slideDown()
                    },
                    hideErrorFu:function(label){
                        label.find('.'+_.errorCl).slideUp()
                    },
                    showEmptyFu:function(label){
                        label.find('.'+_.emptyCl).slideDown()
                        _.hideErrorFu(label)
                    },
                    hideEmptyFu:function(label){
                        label.find('.'+_.emptyCl).slideUp()
                    },
                    init:function(){
                        _.form=_.me                     
                        _.labels=$('label',_.form)

                        _.preFu()

                        _.controlsFu()

                        _.form
                            .bind('submit',function(){
                                if(_.validate)
                                    _.submitFu()
                                else
                                    _.form[0].submit()
                                return false
                            })
                            .bind('reset',function(){
                                _.labels.removeClass(_.invalidCl)                                   
                                _.labels.each(function(){
                                    var th=$(this)
                                    _.hideErrorFu(th)
                                    _.hideEmptyFu(th)
                                })
                            })
                        _.form.trigger('reset')
                    }
                }
            _.me||_.init(_.me=th.data({forms:_}))
            typeof o=='object'
                &&$.extend(_,o)
        })
    }
})(jQuery)
$(window).load(function(){
    $('#contact-form').forms({
        ownerEmail:'#'
    })
})
```

--edit3--

```
protected void btn_calculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ltrl_buying_text.Text = Class_R.Load_Form_Text(11);

    lbl_total.Text = calculate();

    pnl_travel_type.Visible = false;
    pnl_img.Visible = false;

    pnl_Buying.Visible = true;
    btn_Submit.Enabled = true;
}
```

that is not in jquery it's in codebehind...

Comment: Jquery code is at form.js linked above

Comment: It is in the code behind, not in js

Answer (score 1):

Well since you did not post your jQuery code, I will suggest this:

Markup:

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btn_calculate" 
                CssClass="button TheLinkButton" data-type="submit" 
                Text="Calculate">
</asp:LinkButton>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.TheLinkButton').click(function() {
        // Do link button click logic here


        // If you do not want the server click to fire, 
        // then uncomment the return false; line below
        // return false;
    });
});
```

---

> Note: I have added a class named `TheLinkButton` to the `LinkButton`'s markup in order to simplify the jQuery selector to use a class name (via the `.` notation).

Comment: I guess I could not explain myself, **I want to fire onclick event.** If I remove `data-type="submit"`, it fires correctly even I enter nothing to email field, otherwise I cannot fire onclick...